# Why doesn't dkim sign the letter?

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, dkim, opendkim

I have configured DKIM:

```
Dec 27 11:10:03 mailer opendkim[378]: OpenDKIM Filter v2.11.0 starting (args: -x /etc/opendkim.conf)
Dec 27 11:10:10 mailer postfix/postfix-script[551]: warning: symlink leaves directory: /etc/postfix/./makedefs.out
Dec 27 11:10:10 mailer postfix/postfix-script[719]: starting the Postfix mail system
Dec 27 11:10:10 mailer postfix/master[721]: daemon started -- version 3.4.13, configuration /etc/postfix
```

But the letters are not signed, I connect on port 25, there are no errors, tell me in which configuration file can there be problems?
My key is being verified

```
opendkim-testkey: using default configfile /etc/opendkim.conf
opendkim-testkey: key loaded from /etc/postfix/dkim/mail.private
opendkim-testkey: checking key 'mail._domainkey.domain.com'
opendkim-testkey: key not secure
opendkim-testkey: key OK
```

Configured exactly as in this guide https://www.linuxbabe.com/mail-server/setting-up-dkim-and-spf

Please tell me which way to look and where I could be wrong with the settings. Thanks in advance to everyone!

grep Socket /etc/opendkim.conf ->

```
# Socket smtp://localhost
# ##  Socket socketspec
#Socket                  inet:8892@localhost
#Socket    inet:12301@localhost
Socket inet:8891@localhost
#Socket    local:/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock
```

---

```
sammy@mailer:~$ grep -e 8891 -e unix /etc/postfix/main.cf
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [opendkim-testkey: key not secure](https://serverfault.com/questions/1048491/opendkim-testkey-key-not-secure)

Comment: What is the output of `grep Socket /etc/opendkim.conf`?

Comment: @Paul 
`# Socket smtp://localhost
# ##  Socket socketspec
#Socket                  inet:8892@localhost
#Socket    inet:12301@localhost
#Socket    local:/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock`

Comment: Please [edit](https://serverfault.com/posts/1088302/edit) the question to include the output (it makes it easier to read because `opendkim` and indeed nearly all configuration files interpret new lines, and I don't know where the lines begin and end within a comment.)

Comment: @Paul ok sorry)

Comment: @Paul i updated the question

Comment: Please post the output of `grep -e 8891 -e unix /etc/posfix/main.cf`.

Comment: @Paul i updated the question

Comment: @Paul I am getting an error like this when posting a message  `warning: connect to Milter service inet:localhost:8891: Connection refused`

Comment: @Paul ^ I fixed this mistake by accidentally adding a number when editing socket

Comment: @Paul Now I'm connecting to the socket, but the signature still does not happen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132639/discussion-between-paul-and-oleksandr).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears you have accidentally missed the section in the tutorial titled "Connect Postfix to OpenDKIM", which configures OpenDKIM on Unix domain sockets instead of the default TCP configuration.

The `postfix` process is chrooted in `/var/spool/postfix`, so supporting Unix sockets requires creating a directory for the sockets with appropriate permissions:

```
sudo mkdir /var/spool/postfix/opendkim
sudo chown opendkim:postfix /var/spool/postfix/opendkim
```

Change the `opendkim` configuration to support domain sockets:

```
sudo nano /etc/opendkim.conf
```

Change to match:

```
#Socket inet:8891@localhost
Socket local:/var/spool/postfix/opendkim/opendkim.sock
```

Edit `main.cf` to support the configuration:

```
sudo nano /etc/postfix/main.cf
```

Change:

```
smtpd_milters = local:opendkim/opendkim.sock
non_smtpd_milters = $smtpd_milters
```

Restart both processes:

```
sudo systemctl restart opendkim postfix
```