# Configurating DKIM and SPF, key not secured

Tags: ubuntu, email, dkim, opendkim

On a Ubuntu 20.04 VPS, installing opendkim via
`sudo apt install opendkim opendkim-tools` proceeds as expected, following the [steps provided here](https://www.linuxbabe.com/mail-server/setting-up-dkim-and-spf).

However, upon testing, while e-mails get sent in practice to the targetted mailbox with a very low spam score (3.9) and thus percolate outside of spam filetering,

```
sudo opendkim-testkey -d domain.tld -s default -vvv
```

returns unexpected and somewhat contradictory conclusions:

```
opendkim-testkey: key not secure
opendkim-testkey: key OK
```

The key is OK, but not secure.  This puts into doubt the 'OK' bit.  What has to be done to make the key secure?

*Update*

Following suggestion in comments,
contents of `opendkin.conf` follow:

```
Syslog                  yes
Logwhy                  yes
UMask                   007

Canonicalization        relaxed/simple
Mode                    sv
SubDomains              no

AutoRestart         yes
AutoRestartRate     10/1M
Background          yes
DNSTimeout          5
SignatureAlgorithm  rsa-sha256
Socket                  local:/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock
PidFile               /run/opendkim/opendkim.pid
OversignHeaders         From
TrustAnchorFile       /usr/share/dns/root.key

include
UserID                opendkim
KeyTable           refile:/etc/opendkim/key.table
SigningTable       refile:/etc/opendkim/signing.table
ExternalIgnoreList  /etc/opendkim/trusted.hosts
InternalHosts       /etc/opendkim/trusted.hosts
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [opendkim-testkey: key not secure](https://serverfault.com/questions/1048491/opendkim-testkey-key-not-secure)

Comment: alas, not, as the conf file already has `TrustAnchorFile /usr/share/dns/root.key` set

Comment: Do you have dnssec configured in your DNS records?

Comment: Ah, no.  So that explains the situation.  Do you have a judgement call on criticality of said entry?